# navigate does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a register page, when the user is registered I want the application to move him to the home page.
I have a login page and after a login the user is moved to the home page.
I tried doing the same thing with my register page but it won't move the user to the homepage. I don't have any error and the application won't crash. This is the code:

handlePress:

```
  handlePress(navigate){
    if(this.state.password == this.state.verify){
      firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(newUser){
        //good
         navigate("home");
      }).catch(function(error){
        //bad
      });
    }else{
      //password not match, show error.
    }
  }
```

The user does gets signup and showing up in the firebase.

this is where I call handlePress:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.subButtom} onPress={()=>this.handlePress(navigate)}>
  <Text style={styles.subTxt}>
  Register
  </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

navigate (navigate is in the render function):

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

this is working on my login page but not in the register page.

Comment: try navigate.replace("home") or navigate.push("home")

Comment: Thanks but it's not working.

Comment: check if it enters , `console.log("Im here")` or `Alert.alert("Im here")` if it lands on the navigator you can try to just `this.props.navigation.replace("home")` or `this.props.navigation.replace({id: 'home'})`

Comment: I tried to check, the code inside firebaseref.auth()... does not run at all.

Comment: if nothing happens inside then its not really a navigator problem

Comment: When I only console.log I can see the log. but it's like executing only 1 line of code.